# Spring - Get driverClassName from bean datasource

Tags: java, spring

I have a spring xml file configuring database connection :

```
<bean name="dataSource" id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/****" />
    <property name="username" value="****" />
    <property name="password" value="****" />
</bean>
```

Why can I get url, username and password but not driverClassName in Java ?

```
@Autowired
private DriverManagerDataSource dataSource;

private void connect() {
    // dataSource.getDriverClassName() does not exist
    final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    final String DB_URL = dataSource.getUrl();
    final String USER = dataSource.getPassword();
    final String PASS = dataSource.getUsername();
}
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why doesn't the method exist? Well - how about: **Because you don't need it**

In dinosaur-java (pre jdbc 4.0) you had to explicitly register your jdbc drivers - typically by loading the class in a `Class.forName (driverName)` call. That's no longer needed. All you need is the driver jar to be on the classpath, a proper jdbc- url, a username and a password. So that's all you get here.

Comment: I did not know that, thank you for your clear and concise answer.